# Given input signal $s$ and convolution kernel $a$, find the corresponding convolution matrix and the output signal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convolution, circulant-matrices

> Determine the discrete convolution of the signal $s = (9 \ \ 9 \ \ 6 \ \ 9)^T$ and the convolution kernel $a = (2 \ \ 3 \ \ 1 \ \ 5)^T$. Given the convolution matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{4 \times 4}}$, as well as the result of the convolution $\hat s = a * s$.

I'm having trouble understanding how to derive the convolution matrix. From some of the videos I have seen, it's basically the circulant matrix of the input signal:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}9&9&6&9\\ 9&9&9&6\\ 6&9&9&9\\ 9&6&9&9\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I thought that the convolution matrix should be the circulant matrix of the convolution kernel:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&5&1&3\\ 3&2&5&1\\ 1&3&2&5\\ 5&1&3&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Interestingly enough, multiplying the first matrix by $a$ and multiplying the second matrix by $s$ gives me the same result:

$$\begin{pmatrix}9&9&6&9\\ 9&9&9&6\\ 6&9&9&9\\ 9&6&9&9\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\\ 1\\ 5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&5&1&3\\ 3&2&5&1\\ 1&3&2&5\\ 5&1&3&2\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}9\\ 9\\ 6\\ 9\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}96\\ 84\\ 93\\ 90\end{pmatrix}$$

I just want to know which convolution matrix is correct, if any. If none of them are correct, how can I find the correct one?

Here is the problem in German (please ignore the answers in the image as they are wrong):

---

[image]

Comment: In [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44439/21075), I got a Toeplitz matrix, not a circulant one. The convolution of two sequences of length $4$ is a sequence of length $4 + 4 - 1 =7$. Check the matrix dimensions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I doubled checked and the question states that $A \in \mathbb{4 \times 4}$ and $\hat s \ \ \text{is} \ \ 4 \times 1$.

Comment: I haven't heard that term before. In German it's "Faltungsmatrix" which is "Convolution Matrix // Convolution Kernel".

Comment: Yeah sure. Can you understand German?

Comment: I read some German. However, I remain confused. What is given? What exactly is to be computed?

Comment: We are given the input signal $s$ and the convolution kernel $a$. We have to find the convolution matrix $A$ and the result vector $\hat s = a * s$

Comment: Then that means we are not using linear convolution, rather a circular one.

Comment: Then the matrix $A$ in the print-screen is almost correct.

Comment: What can I change to make it exactly correct?

Comment: Take a look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCukt.png). Write the kernel in the first column, then shift it downwards for every following column.